# Laravel PayPal Multivendor System

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to develop a multivendor payment system in Laravel where each user is able to add their PayPal `client_id` and `client_secret`. So that each user is able to receive their payment in their own account.

If I understand correctly, so far Paypal adaptive allows for such kinds of system. However, it adaptive payment [doesn't support](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/gs-AdaptivePayments/) any more new accounts/implementation.

So any suggestion that how can I achieve that? Any resource to tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have and account's client ID and secret, use that information to set up and process any checkouts with payments toward that particular account. There is no complexity for a checkout that pays a particular account you have credentials for.

If you need to pay multiple accounts *simultaneously* (which your question does not specify), which is something adaptive payments could do, there is no solution for this.

Comment: I am sorry if it is not clear enough. I want to set up multiple PayPal accounts in one app. Imagine that, I have 100 users where they can able to set up their client id and secret from the backend. Once their client pay from their store (subdomain for each user), the user will able to receive their payment to their set up PayPal account. That's what I am expecting to integrate. @Preston-PHX

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer addresses that: You can use each clientid+secret to set up a checkout that processes payments towards each particular account. There can be 1 user or 1,000,000 users that you process payments for in this way.